# How to redirect tomcat console log to files? Tomcat started via windows bat

Tags: windows, tomcat, logging

When Tomcat is started as service it puts its output log in:

```
\logs\stderr.log  
\logs\stdout.log
```

How to write this log files when Tomcat started as BAT in windows?

P.S.: I tried to start Tomcat with:

```
call startup > ../logs/consolelog.log 2<&1
```

But output of `consolelog.log` has only 5 lines

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Java\Tomcat 5.0"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Java\Tomcat 5.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Java\Tomcat 5.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Java\Tomcat 5.0\bin\bootstrap.jar"
```

and lot of output in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `conf/logging.properties` and change this line

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

to

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Then it will only log to `catalina.<date>.log`, not to the console.

Comment: This didn't work for me though :/

Comment: Did not work though. w/ Tomcat 8 running on  Windows as a service

Comment: What does the 1 in 1catalina mean ?

Answer (score 6):

For those to which the accepted answer does not work:

I had the same situation, but I was using (liferay -> tomcat) startup.bat and it always opened up tomcat console. The way to edit the startup.bat file, so that it outputs the log into a file was like this:

Look for the line:

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

and edit it, so it looks like this:

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" run >..\logs\outputfile.log 2>&1 start %CMD_LINE_ARGS% run >..\logs\outputfile.log 2>&1
```

You can find your output in the tomcat's logs folder. The file is outputfile.log.
The solution is an experimentation with what I found on [this page](http://goo.gl/8uyM66), which was linked from [this forum](http://goo.gl/Wea4c0). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't double check, but I think you can just redirect the console I/O in a standard Windows and Unix manner:

```
tomcart-start > C:\mylog\log.txt
```

Comment: it's not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the startup.bat

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda run >..\logs\server.log 2>&1 start %CMD_LINE_ARGS% >..\logs\server.log 2>&1
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, in your case I would not use **call startup**.

Try:

```
catalina run > ..\logs\consolelog.all 2>&1
```

or

```
catalina run > ..\logs\consolelog.out 2> ..\logs\consolelog.err
```

**call startup** at the end calls **catalina start**, which starts a new console. On the other hand **catalina run** runs in the same console, and you can redirect your stdout, stderr as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

File: catalina.bat

Lines:

```
rem Comment out the line below like in this script extract
rem set _EXECJAVA=start "%TITLE%" %_RUNJAVA%
rem Add instead replace it with
set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJAVA%
```

Next, find the line making the final Java call (add the redirection as below after the 3 dots):

```
%_EXECJAVA% %CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG% %LOGGING_MANAGER% ... 2>&1 >c:\temp\tomcat.log
```

You will then get your stdout and stderr streams in the file c:\temp\tomcat.log